# R : ploltly update y value with button updatemenues r

Tags: r, updates, r-plotly

I have problem with plotly. I try to update value `y` with `layout` -> `updatemenus` but don't function, so I update column of data frame with shiny but when I would a update `y` with new value of column of data frame.

```
    plot_ly(table_inter,x = ~cyear,y= ~Freq.0,color = ~clib_article,type='bar',key=key)%>%
      layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Nbr unité vendu'),xaxis = list(title = 'Année'),updatemenus=list(list(
        active = -1,
        type= 'buttons',

        buttons = list(
          list(
            method = "restyle",
            args = list(list(y =list(~Freq.1),type = 'bar)),
            label = "Annuelle"

          ),

          list(
            method = "restyle",
            args = list(list(y =list(~Freq.0),type='lines')),
            label = "Semestrielle"

          )

        ))))
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: the value of y dont update with updatemenus, because i update my dataframe and i would update the value of y